# Forge server "Invalid redirect_uri" error

Tags: autodesk-forge

Having exactly rewritten the [code as in tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/datamanagement/hubs/net), I still have the following error after clicking "sign in' button:

https://auth.autodesk.com/as/authorization.oauth2?client_id=82EkDyY5DZn27fvdfXJvPkDBue8ZH4Au&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fforge%2Fcallback%2Foauth&response_type=code&pfidpadapterid=Oauth2OpenTokenIDPAdapter&scope=data:read%20viewables:read&aud=https%3A%2F%2Fautodesk.com%2Faud%2Fajwtexp60

I have no idea what to do.

upd:
after correcting callback URL entered problem passed,
but right after on the next step another problem comes:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
>
> An error has occurred.
> Error calling Gettoken: {"developerMessage":"The client_id (application key)/client_secret are not valid","errorCode":"AUTH-003","more info":"https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/"}
> Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException
>  в Autodesk.Forge.ThreeLeggedApi.d__18.MoveNext() --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение --- в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) в Autodesk.Forge.ThreeLeggedApi.d__17.MoveNext() --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение --- в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() в forgeSample.Controllers.Credentials.<CreateFromCodeAsync>d__17.MoveNext() в C:\Users\rodin\Desktop\forgeSX\forgeSX\Controllers\OAuthController.cs:строка 103 --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение --- в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() в forgeSample.Controllers.OAuthController.d__4.MoveNext() в C:\Users\rodin\Desktop\forgeSX\forgeSX\Controllers\OAuthController.cs:строка 72 --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение --- в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) в System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__1`1.MoveNext() --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение --- в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext() --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение --- в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext() --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение --- в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) в System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()

Comment: Could you share what error code you saw after clicking the sign-in button? Most like that your callback URL entered [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/create-app/#step-2-register-an-app) is not `http://localhost:3000/api/forge/callback/oauth`

Comment: Yes, that is the cause. Thanks.